# In jquery how to read file.txt from the same drive & split the data into string array?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a file new.txt and a html file new.html.

In new.txt there are set of data separated by new line.

In new.html which is in the same drive i want to read the from the text file & then write to a `<div id='x'> </div>`. Is it possible without any server programming & just use jquery to do it.

I tried `$.get()` and `load()` but was not able to get anywhere with the code. It displayed the file contents once i used the `load()` but was not able to manipulate data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [file API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) if you are using HTML 5.

Always check for browser support!

Comment: Thank you. But i want it to work on internet explorer 8. Can you help me on that.

Comment: This might help: http://blog.filepicker.io/post/33906205133/hacking-a-file-api-onto-ie8